# How can we prove $\left.\mathcal F_{σ}\right|_{\{\:σ\:\le\:\tau\:\}}=\left.\mathcal F_{σ\:\wedge\:\tau}\right|_{\{\:σ\:\le\:\tau\:\}}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

Let $I\subseteq\overline{\mathbb R}$, $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$ be a filtration on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $\sigma,\tau:\Omega\to I\cup\{\sup I\}$ be $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$-stopping times. Moreover, let $\mathcal F_\tau$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra of the $\tau$-past, i.e. $$\mathcal F_\tau=\{A\in\mathcal A:A\cap\{\tau\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t\},$$ and $\left.\mathcal F\right|_A:=\{A\cap B:B\in\mathcal F\}$ denote the trace of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on a set $A$.

> Are we able to show that $$\left.\mathcal F_{\sigma}\right|_{\{\:\sigma\:\le\:\tau\:\}}=\left.\mathcal F_{\sigma\:\wedge\:\tau}\right|_{\{\:\sigma\:\le\:\tau\:\}}\tag1$$, where $a\wedge b:=\min(a,b)$?

I only was able to show that $$\left.\mathcal F_{\sigma}\right|_{\{\:\sigma\:\le\:\tau\:\}}\subseteq\mathcal F_{\sigma\:\wedge\:\tau}=\mathcal F_\sigma\cap\mathcal F_\tau\tag2,$$ but I struggle to obtain the desired claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the equality in (2).  If $$ E \in\left.\mathcal F_{\sigma}\right|_{\{\:\sigma\:\le\:\tau\:\}}\subseteq\mathcal F_{\sigma\:\wedge\:\tau},$$  then $E=E \cap \{\sigma \leq \tau\}$ so $E \in \mathcal F_{\sigma \wedge \tau}|_{\sigma \leq \tau}$.  The reverse inclusion is immediate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you write that the reverse inclusion "is immediate", you mean that it is immediate by the equality in $(2)$, which yields $\mathcal F_{\sigma\:\wedge\:\tau}\subseteq\mathcal F_\sigma$, right?

Comment: While I'm still interested in my former comment, please take a look at my follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4084334/47771. Probably you can help there as well!